# Install opencv with conda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

This question is different from "How do I install Python OpenCV through Conda?" because that question was asked more than 5 years ago, when all packages had different versions.  I tried ALL answers to that question, and neither worked.  See the text of question for details.

How to install opencv with conda now, in July 2019?  On a freshly installed anaconda, I did `conda update conda` (succesfully) then tried the following:

```
(base) C:\Users\mlearning>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv'

(base) C:\Users\mlearning>conda install -c menpo opencv3
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: (goes into infinite loop, after 10 minutes I pressed ^C)

(base) C:\Users\mlearning>conda install opencv
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Initial quick solve with frozen env failed.  Unfreezing env and trying again.
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package zipp conflicts for:
importlib_metadata -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
path.py -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5'] -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0 -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
zipp
Package importlib_metadata conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0
path.py -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
Package hdf5 conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> h5py==2.9.0=py37h5e291fa_0 -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0']
hdf5
opencv -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.2,<1.10.3.0a0,>=1.8.18,<1.8.19.0a0,>=1.8.20,<1.9.0a0']
h5py -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.1,<1.10.2.0a0,>=1.10.2,<1.10.3.0a0,>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0,>=1.8.18,<1.9.0a0']
pytables -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.1,<1.10.2.0a0,>=1.8.18,<1.8.19.0a0,>=1.8.18,<1.9.0a0']
Package mkl-service conflicts for:
mkl-service
anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> mkl-service==1.1.2=py37hb782905_5

(base) C:\Users\mlearning>conda install -c conda-forge opencv
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Initial quick solve with frozen env failed.  Unfreezing env and trying again.
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package hdf5 conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> hdf5==1.10.4=h7ebc959_0
h5py -> hdf5[version='1.10.1,1.8.17|1.8.17.*,1.8.18|1.8.18.*,>=1.10.2,<1.10.3.0a0,>=1.10.3,<1.10.4.0a0,>=1.8.20,<1.9.0a0']
pytables -> hdf5[version='1.8.18|1.8.18.*,>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0,>=1.8.18,<1.8.19.0a0,>=1.8.18,<1.9.0a0']
hdf5
Package mkl-service conflicts for:
mkl-service
Package importlib_metadata conflicts for:
importlib_metadata
path.py -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Python OpenCV through Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-do-i-install-python-opencv-through-conda)

Comment: Use `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`.  Or better, create a new env for it and let Conda resolve the Python version that's best for it: `conda create --name env_name -c conda-forge opencv`

Comment: @merv - it is not duplicate of that question, because I tried all, I repeat all answers from that question. Neither of them works, which I wrote.

Comment: @merv "Use conda install -c conda-forge opencv"  -  it did not work. In my question there is exactly this command, and what diagnostic it produced. Please read questions more carefully.

Comment: Ah sorry about that: your `conda-forge` attempt was below the scroll and Mac Chrome hides scroll bars by default, so it looked like only the `menpo` try was there. I still think creating a new env is a proper solution though.

Comment: Are you still looking for information/answers on this?

Comment: No, I installed opencv. Don't remember how. It was 8 months ago.

Comment: But if you have a valuable information, please answer to help other members.   Good answers are appreciated.

Comment: @user31264 Do you use the Conda base environment for everything, or were you doing so at the time?

Comment: yes, i used conda for everything on that computer

Comment: @merv Omg man. I just want to say thank you. I've literally spent the last 12 hours trying to fix a tiny problem and this was the fix. Thank you, you hero

Answer (score 18):

I have had countless problems with installing opencv with conda
This is my approach, create an env if you don't already have one

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
conda activate py36
```

Install opencv with `pip` **NOT** `conda`

`pip install opencv-python`

If your still having an issue, uninstall opencv, update ffmpeg

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

then rerun `pip`

**UPDATE 2020**

install pip with you env activate

`conda install pip`

verify pip is in your env

```
whereis
pip: /path/anaconda3/envs/your_env/bin/pip
```

Install opencv with pip

`~/anaconda3/envs/your_env/bin/pip3 install opencv-python`

Comment: _I have had countless problems with installing opencv with conda_ Can you elaborate? Using pip for this should really be a last resort.

Comment: Does not work at June 2020; results in 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found'.

Comment: worked ubuntu 2022 thank you

Comment: Using `pip` in combination with `conda` should be done with care (https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages). Especially, "[...] we recommend first trying to install any package with conda."

Answer (score 8):

Create a complete new environment and let conda deal with compatibilities:

```
conda create -n cv -c conda-forge opencv matplotlib
```

This will create a new environment named "cv" with python, opencv and matplotlib.

Today (Out. 11th, 2019) it installed:

- Python 3.7.3
- OpenCV 4.1.1
- MatPlotLib 3.1.1
- Numpy 1.17.2
- ... and all other dependencies.

Comment: "...let conda deal with compatibilities" : I couldn't agree more! Conda was designed to solve that kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

directly run

```
pip install opencv-python
```

on spyder instead

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem (only hdf5 conflicted).
The reason is using incompatible version python.

How about creating new python3.6 environment before installing openCV?
You can create new environment like this.

> $ conda create -n py36 python=3.6

In addition you should also type this command to activate.

> $ activate py36

Comment: Why not just create the env from the start around the fact that OpenCV is what you want to install? I.e., `conda create -n opencv_env opencv`. If you want Python 3.6 you can specify that as well: `conda create -n opencv_env opencv python=3.6`

Comment: @merv There is no paticular reason.
If I had to say, I didn't know the conda command's notation.

Comment: _How about creating new python3.6 environment before installing openCV?_ You should be using a separate environment for each project anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. Installed it with the following and it is working for me:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

The pypi for the above is at https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue you were having?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
conda install pip
pip install opencv-python
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

`opencv` is now available on the [main anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/opencv), so contrary to older answers there is now no need to use `conda-forge` (unless you need other dependencies that are only available from there) or `pip` (assuming you would prefer to use `conda`).

To create a new environment named `myopencvenv` with opencv, use

```
conda create -n myopencvenv opencv
```